# How to setup https acces to the specific path in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, https

I'm completely new to `Spring` and `MVC`. I'm trying to setup `https` access to the specific section of my application.

I have 2 buttons: `admin` and `user`. When I press `admin` button, I should input login and password to enter the administration section. When I click on `user` button I want to pass in `https` zone and to get certificate from user. And I need  all paths `user/**` to have `https`.

Here is my code

**startPage.jsp**

```
<a href="<c:url value="/admin" />" role="button">Admin</a>
<a href="<c:url value="/user" />" role="button">User</a>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userArea(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        if (getCertificate(request) != null) {
            mv.setViewName("UserArea");
        } else {
            mv.setViewName("error");
        }
        return mv;
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN_ROLE')")
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();

            http.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("j_username")
                    .passwordParameter("j_password")
                    .permitAll();

            http.logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);

        }
    ...
    }
```

I know that now path `users/**` is using `permitAll()`, but help me, please, setup `https` access to this path or give me please some advice where to read some articles. And one more question, when I want to get client certificate, it contains in `HttpServletRequest` argument of `userArea` method, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using spring security as shown below.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/reports" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
```

Below blog will give more info

http://myshittycode.com/2014/06/12/spring-security-forcing-urls-to-use-https/l

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't know Spring well yet, so can you tell me where to place these settings. I did paste them in security.xml file in WEB-INF folder and in web.xml I added 
`<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>`
But It didn't work. And also can I setup these settings without xml files, because I already have class `SecurityConfig`?

Comment: You have to mention this in spring-security.xml and mention this as context param in web.xml file. Refer http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/ for sample spring security project code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did what you said and nothing changed. So your advice didn't work(. I already have some settings in SecurityConfig class, that is why I'd like to setup these settings without security xml files.